# export json object to local storage in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am fetching a JSON object form Firestore that I want to be able to export as a JSON file into my local storage. How can I do that?

Here is an example of my data:

```json
[
   {
      "date":1602214199274,
      "expenseType":{
         "id":"74aa77c2-d3c7-4456-9b5c-71cbefc5cc66",
         "name":"Raw materials",
         "userId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5"
      },
      "id":"ae1d7a8d-2492-46dd-8c69-97ef206e6fab",
      "key":"fd6ec236-6705-4a95-a698-13e2f25f08d2",
      "note":"Fugit quaerat et veritatis doloremque.",
      "supplier":{
         "id":"d55a8495-ec27-42b4-894b-a2a9fa0eb3a4",
         "name":"Yvonne Stokes",
         "phone":"1-!##-!##-####",
         "userId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "totalPrice":{
         "amount":"952.00",
         "currency":"USD"
      },
      "type":"EXPENSE"
   },
   {
      "date":1601695799282,
      "expenseType":{
         "id":"39c5eb85-0377-41fc-a549-ce590146ac26",
         "name":"Equipment",
         "userId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      },
      "id":"cee9d1c8-979c-496f-a56d-95e3f8474823",
      "key":"8c6cd4a2-f940-44be-bbf8-c0cab7631e37",
      "note":"Amet provident itaque neque mollitia.",
      "supplier":{
         "id":"36b51b24-7d07-410b-849c-4c92cb52c41e",
         "name":"Jack Macejkovic",
         "phone":"(!##) !##-####",
         "userId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe"
      },
      "totalPrice":{
         "amount":"378.00",
         "currency":"KHR"
      },
      "type":"EXPENSE"
   },]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can convert it to a string using:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

install async-storage:

```
npm i @react-native-community/async-storage
```

Usage:

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

const storeData = async (value) => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value)
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', jsonValue)
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}
```

Checkout the docs here: https://react-native-community.github.io/async-storage/docs/usage

You can then parse when you retrieve it from local storage:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: There could be download as file.json?

Comment: Whats the reason you want to save it as a json file instead of a string?

Answer (score 2):

React native async storage (https://react-native-community.github.io/async-storage/) is a string only store. So, You will have to convert it to string using `JSON.stringify(json)` and then store it in async storage. It is not equivalent to browser's storage.

If you are using android the `AsyncStorage` size is limited to few MBs (6MB by default). Which can be increased if needed.

If data is too big but it has a format then you can use sql based db https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage (expo version:  https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/sqlite/)

Otherwise you have realm https://realm.io/products/realm-database https://github.com/realm/realm-js